# is_function_pointer<> for <type_traits>

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, c++11

There are these in `<type_traits>`:

```
is_pointer<>
is_function<>
is_member_function_pointer<>
```

But not this:

```
is_function_pointer<>
```

Why is it so?

Comment: `is_pointer` yields true in the case of function pointers, but not pointers to member functions. So `is_member_function_pointer` is a neccessary addition, while `is_function_pointer` is not.  Not saying it wouldn't be useful, just mentioning the distinction.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The traits in [meta.unary.cat] are intended to classify each type into a single category.  Is it a void, integral, pointer, etc.  At this level, pointer-to-function is no different than pointer-to-int.  And note that a pointer to a member is not a pointer.  It is merely an english homonym.

It was intended that every type return true to exactly one trait in [meta.unary.cat].  And in this categorization, both a function pointer and a scalar pointer would both return true under `is_pointer`.

I will note that we did not achieve our objective.  `nullptr_t` escapes our goal.  But we got close.  [Here](http://home.roadrunner.com/~hinnant/TypeHiearchy.pdf) is a graphical representation of the current type_traits classification.

**Update:**

This is a correctly working program with correct output:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

typedef void (*fptr)();
typedef int* intptr;

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::is_function<fptr>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<fptr>::value << '\n';
    std::cout << std::is_pointer<intptr>::value << '\n';
}

0
1
1
```

Comment: pointer to function is actually very different from `int*`.  One (`int*`) can portably be round-tripped through `void*`, but function pointers can't.

Comment: @Ben : I think that's true of member function pointers, not plain function pointers. I'm not positive though.

Comment: @ildjarn: Memory models with different sizes for code and data pointers aren't as prevalent as they [used to be](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Memory_Model), but they aren't uncommon either.  Many embedded systems have several orders of magnitude more code memory than data memory, and differently sized pointers as a result.

Comment: I suspect the non-existence of `is_function_pointer` is also because there is `remove_pointer`, which makes it expressible as `is_pointer<T> && is_function<remove_pointer<T>>`. But for `is_member_function_pointer`, one would need `remove_member_pointer`, which doesn't seem to exist. I wonder why, though?

Comment: Ah I think it would be ambiguous. For `U C::*`, it could yield `U` and `C`. I could imagine that `remove_member_pointer<T>::class_type` would yield `C` and `remove_member_pointer<T>::type` would yield `U` (intuitively). But I can see that it's open to debate.

Comment: @ildjarn: the standard clearly specifies that function (any function) is not an object; and it allows for objects only safe conversion to `void*` and back.

Comment: With the addition of the categories "object pointers" (encapsulates both pointer to object and pointer to void types) and "function pointers" to clause 3 of the FDIS (late change), it would seem to be reasonable to add `is_function_pointer` and `is_object_pointer` again though :)

Answer (score 7):

It does seem like an odd oversight. However, member pointers are always member pointer types, unlike free functions, which can be either pointers types (`void(*)()`) or function types (`void()`). Also `std::is_pointer` never returns true for member pointer types.

However, if you need this functionality, here's an implementation:

```
template<typename testType>
struct is_function_pointer
{
    static const bool value =
        std::is_pointer<testType>::value ?
        std::is_function<typename std::remove_pointer<testType>::type>::value :
        false;
};
```

Comment: Your `value` is not a integral constant expression. Please put that test into the struct and make the `value` `const`.